# How to create a formula with several conditions in crystal

Tags: crystal-reports

I am very new to crystal reports and need help with a formula, think i may be over complicating it

What I basically want is to return the NetWeight

IF

ProductLineID (in the wjcproductline table)  is equal to ProductLineID in wjcPackingLine table

AND

Pallet weight is greater than 1

AND

Line Status is equal to 7

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Kris

Answer (score 0):

basic question you should have googled first before posting it as a question here.

```
if (wjcproductline.ProductLineID = wjcPackingLine.ProductLineID ) and 
   (Pallet_weight>1) and
   (Line_Status=7)
Then NetWeight
```